# Movement based on mouse click XNA

Tags: c#, xna, mouseevent

I'm making a server/client game with movement similar to strategy games like Warcraft 1/2/3 etc.. where the player moves by right clicking on somewhere on the area and the character tries to move there. I'm trying to make the character always go in a straight line towards the point until it gets there (or close enough). The code I'm using now gets the character there but in a weird way.

When I click somewhere under the character (higher Y coordinate) it moves in a straight line, but when I click above it (lower Y coordinate), the character moves like it's making a circle while moving, but it still gets there, only not the way I want it to.

Here's the code that runs every update to move it.

```
        if (this.order == "Move")
        {
            if (Math.Abs(this.orderPos.X - this.warlockPos.X) < this.moveSpeed && Math.Abs(this.orderPos.Y - this.warlockPos.Y) < this.moveSpeed)
            {
                this.warlockPos = this.orderPos;
                this.order = "None";
                this.orderPos = Vector2.Zero;
            }
            else
            {
                delta = this.orderPos - this.warlockPos;
                if (delta.Y == 0)
                {
                    if (delta.X < 0)
                        angle = -90;
                    else
                        angle = 90;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (delta.Y < 0)
                        angle = 180 + Math.Atan(delta.X / delta.Y);
                    else
                        angle = Math.Atan(delta.X / delta.Y); ;
                }
                this.warlockPos = new Vector2(this.warlockPos.X + this.moveSpeed * (float)Math.Sin(angle), this.warlockPos.Y + this.moveSpeed * (float)Math.Cos(angle));
            }
        }
```

this.order == move means the client's last order was to move.
orderPos is the place where the client last told the server the character should move.
warlockPos is the current position of the character (where it was by the end of the previous update).
moveSpeed is just the speed at which it moves.
I use delta and angle to figure out where the character should move in this update.

So, what's making the character move in a circular way when the point it's moving towards is above it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems with this code originating from the use of angles. It's not that you can't use angles, but the code becomes more complicated with this approach and prone to error. Instead, I used some vector methods such as `Length()` to check if the warlock is close to his destination, and `Normalize()` when I covert the delta vector into a unit vector in the same direction and with the magnitude of his moveSpeed (in order to move him that far). Here is what I came up with:

```
if (order == "Move")
{
    Vector2 delta = orderPos - warlockPos;

    if (delta.Length() < moveSpeed)
    {
        warlockPos = orderPos;
        order = "None";
        orderPos = Vector2.Zero;
    }
    else
    {
        delta.Normalize();
        delta *= moveSpeed;
        warlockPos += delta;
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend not use the `this` keyword if it isn't necessary (only if there is another local variable or parameter with the same name). I apologize if this was an intentional style choice. Also, I'd recommend using an enumeration instead for the order variable (for example `order == Orders.Move`).

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly :D! By the way, I had to add this. to everything, but that's because the code is inside a function within a class so there are parameters.

Comment: No problem! Ah, understandable. Happy XNAing!

Comment: Sorry, but could you please help me with something else (This code works perfectly btw ty)? How do I calculate the place(vector2) where a warlock will be knocked towards if he is knocked away from a nearby warlock. So if point A is near point B and point B knocks point A away from itself, towards what point will point A be moving? (I know how to make it move to that point thanks to the code you already gave me but I have no idea how to find that point)

Comment: Sure. You'd use a similar approach by finding the direction you want him to travel, normalizing that vector, and multiplying it by the distance you want him to be pushed. After that, all you need to do is add that vector to his starting position. So: `Vector2 dir = aPos - bPos; dir.Normalize(); dir *= pushDistance; Vector2 endPoint = aPos + dir;`

Comment: I just had an idea. Would this work?

1. Find the delta vector to move the warlock towards the other one as if he was ordered to go there.
2. Get the opposite of that vector
3. Use -delta to move the warlock

This way I'm just using what you already gave me last time

I'm about to try to do it like this, so I'll tell you if it works! But thanks for helping again!

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, that should work. Somehow, I'm curious as to what these warlocks are doing pushing each other around. :P

Comment: If you've ever played Warcraft 3 and you've played the custom map warlocks, that's what I'm trying to mimic. 

But if not, basically, it's a multiplayer game with warlocks in an arena surrounded by lava, which kills the warlocks on contact. The arena shrinks over time too. The last warlock standing wins (or team of warlocks). Warlocks can buy spells, and most spells do damage and apply knockback, meant to knock enemies into the lava with. It's in 2D but in the style of Pokemon (bird's eye view, you can walk in all horizontal directions, but there's no jumping). That's basically it!

Comment: Actually I've seen a video of that, it looked pretty cool. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem again :P. I'm making the first ability that actually uses a projectile, so I need to draw it with an angle depending on where the target point is.

So, if the target point has the same X as the warlock and a different Y it will be 90f, and so on.

Because the formula you gave me for moving has no angle in it (Actually I have no idea because I don;t completely understand it but I don't thin it does) I can't just use that, I don't think. So, can you help me, please?

Comment: Hmm, well it depends on exactly what you want to happen. If you just want the projectile to travel in a direction, you can either use the same method you have more moving the warlock, or give it a velocity (how far it moves every frame). To get the velocity, you can use the same idea as in the answer above (get the direction vector, normalize it, and then multiply it by the speed) and then use that result vector as it's velocity (add it to the position of the projectile every frame). No angle is required for this implementation, unless there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: Well, I want the angle so that I can draw the texture rotated towards the destination. The projectile isn't a ball, it's like a comet (so like ball and tail). Basically, I need the angle so that it looks like the projectile is facing the direction it's travelling in. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, if you get the newly calculated velocity vector of the bullet (as discussed above) you can calculate the angle based on that velocity. This would be `Math.Atan2(velocity.y, velocity.x)`. Keep in mind this will return radians, but that is good because that's what you need. You just need to send that angle in radians into the `spritebatch.Draw` method. You may need to offset the angle by Pi/2 radians depending on which direction the bullet is pointing in the texture.